# v0.8 AggregatorV3Interface.sol , its available in @chainlink/contracts?

Tags: chainlink, brownie

I get a error when i change the version to 0.8 , but works fine with 0.6, how i see the most recent version? , i tried downloaded from npm install @chainlink/contracts --save, but only works with mock mode.

This is my repo:
https://github.com/irwingtello/lottery

Compiling contracts...
Solc version: 0.8.9
Optimizer: Enabled  Runs: 200
EVM Version: Istanbul
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

ParserError: Source "C:/Users/irwin/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol" not found: File not found.
--> contracts/Lottery.sol:4:1:
|
4 | import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ERROR: Unable to load project

Comment: Im getting the same with Brownie compile - doesn't like the reference to 0.8 but switching back to 0.6 is fine....

Comment: Hey @LDJ, check this discussion on github:
https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-py/discussions/306

Its relationed about this repo from NPM packages:
https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts

"As of 1.2.0 and onward all the releases of this package are going to match the @chainlink/contracts NPM tags
So it will look "backwards", but we are starting with 0.2.1"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"As of 1.2.0 and onward all the releases of this package are going to match the `@chainlink/contracts` NPM tags
So it will look `backwards`, but we are starting with `0.2.1`"

Change: `@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1`
To: `@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.1`

https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts/tree/v0.2.1

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1: change the @chainlink/contacts version from @chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1 to @chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.1 in the config file of your project

STEP 2: compile your project using brownie compile

STEP 3: go to https://github.com/StarBlockDAO/SBox-VRF-Random/commit/dbbe6a7933cef13dc905965ceb6d1cfe57818fc2 and get the VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol and save it to your v.08/interfaces directory

STEP 4: compile your project using brownie compile

Answer (score 0):

More elegant solution.

> 1.`yarn add @chainlink/contracts`
> `yarn add @openzeppelin/contracts` #I use it for the SafeMath

> 2. `import"node_modules/@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol"`;
>    `import"node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol"`;